# Upgrading Windows 7 to Windows 8

Tags: windows-7, windows-8, windows-8-upgrade

My wife's PC has Windows 7 Home Premium on it. I ran the Windows 8 Upgrade Assistant on it, and it suggested that I could upgrade it to Windows 8 Pro. I didn't think that was possible; I thought that it could only be upgraded to WindowsRT or maybe Windows 8. Am I wrong?

Comment: afaik, home premium can be upgraded to win 8 pro. Windows 8 Pro has more features than that of windows 8. What's your problem if they permit you to upgrade to a version with more features.

Comment: @Rod: Also if you purchase Windows 8 Pro by 30th Jan 2013 (if I recall correctly) you can get it at a greatly discounted price

Comment: No problem at all, @Khaleel. I'm going to upgrade her PC. And get Windows Media Center while I'm at it.

Comment: Just goes to show how confusing the "RT" nomenclature is, and how many people are disappointed that their RT tablets do not run normal Windows 3rd party apps. MS rightly deserves the flak it has received for confusing people, and even their own Store reps do not properly know the difference between Surface RT and Pro.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

WindowsRT is for Tablets based on ARM architecture.
Where as you can upgrade your Windows 7 Home Premium to Windows 8 PRO.

That means you can not get WindowsRT for your PC, only Windows 8.